Krylov update after column change
(cross-post from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4928836/krylov-update-after-column-change)
Having a Krylov space of A
[V, H] = Arnoldi(A, v1, m),
how to update V and H after adding vector dAk to the kth column, without storing A?
function arnoldi_demo

n = 5;
A = randn(n);

b = randn(n,1);
m = 5;
v1 = randn(n,1);

[V, H] = arnoldi(A, v1, m);

% rank-1 update/perturbation
k = 2;
dAk = 0.1*randn(n,1);

A(:,k) = A(:,k) + dAk;
[V, H] = arnoldi(A, v1, m);

end

function [V, H] = arnoldi(A, v1, m)
if nargin == 0
    n = 10;
    A = randn(n);
    v1 = randn(n,1);
    m = 4;
end
% Input:
% A  - quadratic matrix
% v1 - initial vector (should be of appropriate dimension)
% m  - number of Arnoldi iterations
%
% Output:
% V  - orthonormal basis vectors
% H  - upper Hessenberg matrix

n = size(A, 1);     % Dimension of the matrix A
V = zeros(n, m+1);  % Orthonormal basis vectors
H = zeros(m+1, m);  % Upper Hessenberg matrix

V(:, 1) = v1 / norm(v1);
for j = 1:m
    w = A * V(:, j);
    for i = 1:j
        H(i, j) = V(:, i)' * w;
        w = w - H(i, j) * V(:, i);
    end
    H(j+1, j) = norm(w);
    if H(j+1, j) ~= 0
        V(:, j+1) = w / H(j+1, j);
    else
        break;
    end
end
V = V(:, 1:m);
H = H(1:m, 1:m);
end


Hello. Please read How to ask and add a Minimal, Reproducible Example to your question. As is it will be closed for not being about programming.

What is the issue? What do you mean by "without storing A". Generally speaking Krylov methods don't need to store A as long as you can compute A*x and A^T*b (for Ax=b). However in your code you input A, so I am not sure what you mean "without storing A".

The application here is ICUM, the inverse column update method to solve nonlinear equations by Martinez. At each step, the inverse of the Jacobian is updated column-wise by a full vector. A Krylov representation would scale for large sparse matrices. In short, the goal is to maintain the Krylov space of a large sparse matrix after full column updates.
